# Searching the scrollback buffer

Tags: search, gnome-terminator

Is there any way to search the scrollback buffer in Terminator?
I'd like to be able to search in the logs that are displayed when something is run from the terminal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know about Terminator but an option is to use GNU `screen` (inside any terminal) which comes with its own scroll buffer which can be searched in copy mode with `?`, `/` like in `vi`. It doesn't support case insensitive, regex or whole word search though you can add that as an extension by writing a script that dumps the scroll buffer into a file and do whatever you like with it (including telling `screen` to scroll up to a given location and position the cursor in copy mode).

Comment: The other answer (Ctrl-Shift-F) is preferrable, now

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Terminator then `Ctrl-Shift-F` allows you to search in the scrollback buffer without needing to run `screen` or `tmux`

Comment: I think this should have been marked as the correct answer :) Thanks Aner

Comment: Back in 2013 Stéphane's answer was correct :)