Terminals: Searching output of previous command
Sometimes if I git checkout, or even make, I end up with some unexpected output that makes me ask:

Wait, what?  Let's see that again.

My options are usually:

Move my hand over to the mouse and start scrolling in the terminal.

For commands like dpkg-buildpackage which fail due to a cmake configuration error, they print a massive amount of debug data after the error, so you REALLY have to scroll back a long long ways.


Rerun the command through | more.

but this doesn't work well for commands that change your local state like git checkout.
it's less useful for commands that take a really long time to complete.



Is there a terminal that makes it easy to navigate the output of previous commands?

I added the [tag:scrolling] tag, because what I think you want is a terminal that allows you to search in its scroll-back buffer.

See screen and presumably tmux as well for terminals that can let your search through their scrollback buffer. I'm pretty sure this question has been asked many times here.

Similar/duplicate(?): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67641/searching-the-scrollback-buffer

Tmux and its copy mode. See the manual.

gnome-terminal supports shift+ctrl+f see How to search terminal output. While it is an answer from 2011 confirm it still works in Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS with GNOME Terminal Version 3.52.0 for GNOME 46:


Wow, I didn't know this feature existed. I don't even have to change terminals.  Nice.

Kitty has direct support for this: CtrlShiftG will open the last command’s output (and only that) in a pager (less by default). You can then use the pager’s features to navigate the output.
Quite a few terminal emulators support searching throughout their scrollback buffer: GNOME Terminal, Terminator, etc., along with multiplexers such as screen and tmux.

VTE-based terminal emulators (such as GNOME Terminal), beginning with VTE version 0.76, allow you to jump back to the previous prompt by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Left (similarly, Ctrl+Alt+Right to jump to the next prompt).
In order to make this work, you have to upfront soure the file that's usually placed as /etc/profile.d/vte.sh or /etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh or some similar filename. Your distribution may or may not set it up to automatically do it for you.
